# Dragtozoom both horizontal and vertical

Tags: google-visualization, zooming

Working on a google chart and by dragging to horizontal it zooms. So wondering if its possible to also drag to vertical with the horizontal. I tried to copy the explorer and change horizontal to vertical, that didn't work out.

```
explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                    axis: 'horizontal' },

explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                    axis: 'vertical' },
```

Comment: Setting `explorer.axis` to `'vertical'` should work.  Update your question with a full example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The question is that if its possible for the user to chose whether he/she want to drag horizontal or vertical ? not just one option.

Comment: I tried to use explorer two times with vertical and horzontal, and that didnt work.

Comment: Set `explorer.axis` to `'both'`.